# Deployed SSIS package to SSMS with JSON.net hangs when executed

Tags: ssis, json.net, ssms

I have deployed an SSIS package to SSMS and trying to execute it within SSMS. The package includes the library "json.net". It starts but can run forever. It's stuck at this step, right at the first parsing. It doesn' give any errors or warnings?

[image]
Running the same package in Visual Studio works without any problems. What can cause this?

Comment: I haven't been able to successfully use dlls in ssis or nuget packages. But System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize does work for me

Comment: Did you add the .dlls for JSON.net to the GAC?